# Why rails doesn't want you to create rails projects within existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create another project inside exisiting rails app. My reasoning is that:

- They have some common models which I would be able to link to from the inner app,
- They operate on the same database
- They will have one version control system (no additional configuration and moving required)

Apart from why I want to do that I just want to know **why rails prevents you from doing that?** As of my testing, no conflicts were exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using Rails Engines for this. Here's a Railscasts episode about it. http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines